# Use VisualStateManager to show checkbox in all items of listbox

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, mvvm, visualstatemanager

I'm trying to create an effect similar to the one used in the default email client on Windows phone. When a user taps the very left of a single listbox item, checkboxes appear to the left of all listbox items.

I'd like the appearance of the checkboxes to be fluid (ie requiring FluidLayout). 
When I set up two states in a VisualStateGroup within the ItemTemplate of my items, I am unable to transition between states, as calling VisualStateManager.GoToState requires a view-object (for that item) which I don't have.

How do I make checkboxes appear fluidly inside of all items of a ListBox?

Comment: If you need the same functionality, you should use the ExpanderView (the control you're explicitly referring to) from the Silverlight Toolkit. http://silverlight.codeplex.com/releases/view/75888

Comment: It seems like the ExpanderView is used for displaying the child-messages when a message thread is tapped, not for the checkboxes. Now, if it was just the checkboxes you could point to the MultiselectList. However, I'm not able to use that because the checkboxes appear somewhere in the middle of my items.

Comment: But you know, I just realised that there are several more problems with my approach (like for example retrieving selections once they are set, I guess the selection status could be reflected in the viewmodel). 

I think I'll bite my tongue and use a multiselectlist.